# Property 'onMessage' does not exist on type '{}'. & Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'

Tags: typescript, angular9

I want to try a tutorial for my work to add push messaging in Angular with ffirebase as storage and I learned on a youtube channel entitled: "Getting Started with Firebase Cloud Messaging on the Web - kaptea". on youtube: [this is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEo1avR4ajE)

but there are **three problems (3 errors)** that I can't solve because I'm still learning about Angular. The problems I face here are:

1. ***Property 'onMessage' does not exist on type '{}'.***
2. ***Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.***
3. ***No overload matches this call.***

I've tried various methods, but other problems will arise (other errors). I am tired of these three errors.

Is there anyone here who can help me solve the problem? I really hope to all of you. Thank you :)

this is my code in **messaging.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject";
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingService {

 currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null); // **<= 1. response error here : Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.**

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private angularfireDB: AngularFireDatabase, 
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging
    ) { 
      this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe( 
        (_messaging) => {
          _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging); **// <= 2. response error here** 
          _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
        }
      )
    }

  updateToken(userId: any, token: any){
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      () => {
        const data = {};
        data[userId] = token
        this.angularfireDB.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
      }
    )
  }

  requestPermission(userId: any) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
        this.updateToken(userId, token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('Tidak dapat Permintaan untuk notifikasi', err);
      }
    );
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("Pesan Diterima",payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
      }
    )
  }

  sendPushMessage(title: any, message: any) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let data = {
      "notification": {
        "title": title,
        "body": message,
        "click_action": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "icon": "http://url-to-an-icon/icon.png",
        "sound" : "default"
    },
    "to": "e4nPK1FDI48:APA91bEatNrMf6IfbJEedf0xCqP3nqZZlUx-uaw2XO-rXOqKEFTigxk44wXoRiu7T8wQEqkD38wKEK2v8oiVGRd4UeOZ1sSIiXC-K_CAwBvGVJifZ6VFX2EVvZuqN6t1NtduuTZoqjNQ"
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let postData = JSON.stringify(data);
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let url= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    this.httpClient.post(url, postData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'key=AAAAltQI6co:APA91bHbRm_28dsmuHLbbBjKWjQOMac2VC_gHv9UT6OsiDVhqM-U4jI0tMukWzaHcJHJkZP7317hmMSFv3kGmSK-AxUrIc46pB-br_rNy5bj8ASn1CdE_GzNoW6QF3mXaZL-1r1GN3iC')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
    })
    .subscribe((response: Response) => { // **<= 3. response error here : No overload matches this call.**
      console.log(response)
    },
    (err: Response) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Error Coy" + err);
    });
  }

}
```

this my firebase-messaging.sw.js :

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});


const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

i'm using angular fire version like this :

```js
"@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~11.0.0",
    "admin-lte": "^3.0.5",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^8.1.2",
    "idb": "^5.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

this is the error image I have taken :
[this all error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpFUy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed my problem by matching the version of importScript inside the firebase-messaging-sw.js and the version of firebase install in package.json

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.  You are likely to get downvoted if you do not provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before. I added "AngularFireMessaging" to the code below.

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
        (_messaging: AngularFireMessaging) => {
            _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
            _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue, or are you saying you have tried this but still need help? If the latter, consider opening a new question (or comment perhaps a comment).